# Set opacity of div background to transparent without changing text

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

How do I set the opacity of a div background without affecting the text in `hero-text`? Right now `hero-text` inherits the opacity of `ion-slide`.

```
<style>
.slider {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.slide {
    background-size: cover; 
}
#one { 
    background: url(img/walkthrough-1.png) no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#two {
    background: url(img/walkthrough-2.png) no-repeat;   
}
#three {
    background: url(img/walkthrough-3.png) no-repeat; 
}
.splash {
    bottom: 0px;
}
.hero-text {
}
</style>

<ion-content class="splash" scroll="false">
    <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide id="one"><div class="hero-text">Test</div></ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to only adjust the opacity of `<ion slide id="xxx">` then I recommend breaking your `.hero-text` div out and adjusting your styling as necessary to keep your design correct.

With CSS you can adjust the opacity of a background color -- `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` -- which will create a 50% opaque black background color and not affect any children elements. But if you want to reduce the opaqueness of a background image then your only means are to use `opacity` which will of course affect children.

I used the same concept on a website that also used a "hero image" and I wanted the background image to fade in/out without affecting any text. You may need to use the following CSS to properly place everything:

```
.hero-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.hero-wrapper > .bg {
  background: ...;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.hero-wrapper > .text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

This should work, although it was freehand. Let me know if you want me to explain this anymore or provide a working example. Cheers ~

**Edit**

Here is a working example of my recommendation via Plnkr :)
[Plnkr Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/IY6pOaXMkT0ubI2xSQPm/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you please provide a working example?